# Create yasnippet placeholder in lisp expression

Tags: yasnippet

I am trying to write a snippet to generate different python based on which directory I am in, as in some directories, I am using an older version of python.  The snippet is

```
# key: log
# name: logger
# --
`(if (string-match "/projects/old" default-directory )
     "logger.info('$1: {}'.format($1))"
   "logger.info(f'$1: {$1}')" )
`
```

This sort of works.  It correctly figures out the new/old problem, but yasnippet is not paying attention to the placeholders.  An older version using just

```
     "logger.info('$1: {}'.format($1))"
```

processed the placeholders as expected, but obviously did not generate both forms.  What do I do to enable placeholders inside the return value of a lisp expression?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was answered on [the gitlab site](https://github.com/joaotavora/yasnippet/issues/1057#issuecomment-657617309).  Duplicating it here in case someone finds this page first.

> Yes, yasnippet doesn't support interpreting expanded strings in
> snippet syntax. I suggest making a # type: command instead:

```
# key: log
# name: logger
# type: command
# --
(yas-expand-snippet
  (if (string-match "/projects/old" default-directory )
       "logger.info('$1: {}'.format($1))"
     "logger.info(f'$1: {$1}')"))
```